# split links in text file PHP

Tags: php

I have a text file which contains many (over 5000) links. Like this:

```
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
http://www.website.com/rgfdefvrggh
```

etc etc....

I'm trying to fetch each link at a time and do stuff with it....

so one by one, get the link `do something` and then move on to the next....

I don't know how i would split the links up...

they're all in a .txt file, separated by a line break.

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to read your file in an array, one element per line. For example:

```
$links = file('data.txt');
foreach($link in $links) {
    // do something with $link
}
```

Comment: How exactly would i accomplish that? also, what if, there isn't a line break? thanks

Comment: @Nav: Accomplish what exactly? If there is no line break then there has to be *something* that constitutes your "file format". Depends on what that would be.

Comment: ah, just seen the edit. Don't worry about the other question, was just curious. Thanks

Comment: I get an error when trying your code... on the foreach line. what am i supposed to define $links as? thanks

Comment: @Nav: Uh, it's in the very first line?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Here is an example from php.net:

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$f=fopen("file.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while (!feof($f))
{
$x=fgetc($f);
// The line above stores a character in $x.
echo $x;
}
fclose($f);
```